# representing a matrix by a column vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-calculus

Below, $M$ and $A$ are $n \times n$ real symmetric matrices. We can define a column vector as

\begin{align}
    x := \begin{bmatrix}
           M_{11} \\
           M_{12} \\
           \vdots \\
           M_{1n}\\
           M_{21}\\ 
           M_{22}\\
           \vdots \\
           M_{nn}
         \end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}\qquad (1)
  \end{align}
So now we can write the matrix in terms of this column vector by
$$
M_{ij} =: x_{n(i-1)+j} \ \forall i,j \in [1,n].\qquad (2)
$$
I understand this representation as it can trivially be checked for choosing values of $i,j$. But my problem is from here on.

The Kronecker Delta function can then be used to represent a matrix $A$ by writing

$$
\delta_{il}\delta_{jk} =: A_{n(i-1)+j, n(k-1)+l} \ \forall i,j,k,l \in [1,n] \qquad (3)
$$
which then leads to
$$
x^\top A x = \sum_{i,j,k,l}^n M_{ij}M_{kl}\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}. \qquad(4)
$$

How are equations (3), and (4) justified?  Is this obvious?  I am not able to see why. I am completely clear on equations (1) and (2) though.

I am looking for a thorough explanation or proof as to why (3), (4) are correct. Thanks.

Comment: Potentially helpful: in the [notation of this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), your vector is $x = \operatorname{vec}(A^T)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your comment. I'm not too sure how I can use that in proving or understanding (3) or (4) though.

Comment: I suspect that you copied your $A$ wrong.  That is, in order to get (4), I think we should have 
$$
\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} =: A_{n(i-1)+j, n(k-1)+l} \ \forall i,j,k,l \in [1,n] 
$$
(I altered the left hand side).

Comment: In fact, having gone through the other computation I see that doesn't lead to (4) either.  I'm not sure what's going on here, but hopefully you find my answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we could express what's going on as follows:

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis vectors of $\Bbb R^n$ (so that the $j$th entry of $e_i$ is $\delta_{ij}$).  Let $E_{ij}$ denote the square matrix $e_i e_j^T$ (that is, the $p,q$ entry of $E_{ij}$ is $\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}$).

The Kronecker product is particularly useful since we can now write
$$
e_{n(i-1) + j} = e_i \otimes e_j
$$

Your matrix $A$ can therefore be written as
$$
A = \sum_{i,j=1}^n (e_i \otimes e_j)(e_j \otimes e_i)^T = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n E_{ij} \otimes E_{ji}
$$
With that, we now have
$$
\begin{align*}
x^T A x &= \operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T \left( \sum_{i,j = 1}^n E_{ij} \otimes E_{ji} \right) \operatorname{vec}(M^T) = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n \operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T(E_{ij} \otimes E_{ji})\operatorname{vec}(M^T)
\\ & = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n \operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T \operatorname{vec}(E_{ji}M^TE_{ij})
= \sum_{i,j = 1}^n \operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T \operatorname{vec}(E_{ji}M^TE_{ij})
\\ & = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n \operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T \operatorname{vec}(e_j[e_i^TM^Te_i]e_j^T)
=
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n M_{ii}\operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T \operatorname{vec}(E_{jj})
\\ & = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n M_{ii}\operatorname{vec}\left(\sum_{p,q=1}^n M_{pq} E_{qp}\right)^T \operatorname{vec}(E_{jj}) 
\\ &= 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n \sum_{p,q=1}^n M_{ii} M_{pq}\operatorname{vec}(E_{qp})^T \operatorname{vec}(E_{jj}) = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n \sum_{p,q = 1}^n M_{ii}M_{pq} \delta_{qj}\delta_{pj}
\\ & = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n M_{ii} M_{jj} = \operatorname{tr}(M)^2
\end{align*}
$$

---

Here's the computation assuming that you meant to type 
$$
\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} =: A_{n(i-1)+j, n(k-1)+l} \ \forall i,j,k,l \in [1,n]
$$
as I explain in my comment.  In this case, we have $A = I \otimes I$ (which is to say that $A$ is the $n^2 \times n^2$ identity matrix) so that
$$
\begin{align*}
x^TAx &= \operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T (I \otimes I) \operatorname{vec}(M^T)
= \operatorname{vec}(M^T)^T\operatorname{vec}(I\,M^T\,I)
\\ & = \operatorname{tr}(MM^T) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n M_{ij}^2
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:731610/FULLTEXT01.pdf%22 Page 23, equations 3.118-3.122 is what I was trying to understand.  I guess there are mistakes in these equations?  Let me go through all of your post now, I will likely have questions.  Thanks a lot this is very helpful.

Comment: So do you mean that, $$ x^\top A x = \sum_{i,j,k,l}^n M_{ij}M_{kl}\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}=Tr(MM^\top)=Tr(M^2)? $$ Since $M$ is symmetric, $M=M^\top$.  That PDF is confusing me.  Thanks.

Comment: I actually ended up with $[\operatorname{tr}(M)]^2$ for the first part.  I can't be sure if the mistake is mine or theirs.

Comment: As you can see though, my second result is $\operatorname{tr}(MM^T)$, which coincides with $\operatorname{tr}(M^2)$ in the case that $M$ is symmetric.  If $M$ is supposed to be symmetric, then my best guess is that they meant to describe $A$ as I do in the second section of my answer.